# Menu I cannot get to work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I cannot get this code to work - what I want is that when I hover over the circle the menu appears then if I move the mouse off the circle or menu it disappears. Anything I try and do is VERY buggy, such as onmouseover on circle and then onmouseout on menu the menu seems to disappear after I leave the circle, I have tried using other constructs than Divs but still no luck, at a loss I decided to post here to see if anyone can help. Please find code below:

JS:

```
<script>

function circleAnimOn() {
    //show menu
    document.getElementById("cssmenuDiv").style.display="block";
    document.getElementById("cssmenuDiv").style.visibility="visible";
}

function circleAnimOff() {
    //hide menu
    document.getElementById("cssmenuDiv").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("cssmenuDiv").style.visibility="hidden";
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<body>

<div class="divCircle" id="divCircle" onMouseOver="circleAnimOn();">
</div>

<div class="cssmenuDiv" id="cssmenuDiv"><!-- cssmenuDiv -->

<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li class='active '><a href='index.html'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li class='has-sub '><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li class='has-sub '><a href='#'><span>Product 1</span></a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a></li>
               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li class='has-sub '><a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a></li>
               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a></li>
               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>About</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>

</div><!-- cssmenuDiv -->
```

CSS:

```
body {

  text-align:center;
}

#divCircle
{
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    background-color:#CCC;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
border:2px solid;
border-radius:25px;
-moz-border-radius:25px; /* Firefox 3.6 and earlier */
} 

#divCircle:hover {
    background-color:#093;  
}

#circle { width: 50px; height: 50px; background: red; -moz-border-radius: 50px; -webkit-border-radius: 50px; border-radius: 50px;}

.cssmenuDiv {
    display:none;
    visibility:hidden;
    margin-left:750px;

}

/* Some stylesheet reset */
#cssmenu > ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    line-height: 1;
}

/* The container */
#cssmenu > ul {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 150px;
}

    /* The list elements which contain the links */
    #cssmenu > ul li {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 150px;   
    }

        /* General link styling */
        #cssmenu > ul li a {
            /* Layout */
            display: block;
            position: relative;
            margin: 0;
            border-top: 1px dotted #fff;
            border-bottom: 1px dotted #d9d9d9;
            padding: 11px 20px;
            width: 110px;

            /* Typography */
            font-family:  Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            color: #3dafea;
            text-decoration: none;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
            font-size: 13px;
            font-weight: 300;

            /* Background & effects */
            background: #eaeaea;
        }

        /* Rounded corners for the first link of the menu/submenus */
        #cssmenu > ul li:first-child>a {
            border-top-left-radius: 4px;
            border-top-right-radius: 4px;
            border-top: 0;
        }

        /* Rounded corners for the last link of the menu/submenus */
        #cssmenu > ul li:last-child>a {
            border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
            border-bottom: 0;
        }


        /* The hover state of the menu/submenu links */
        #cssmenu > ul li>a:hover, #cssmenu > ul li:hover>a {
            color: #fff;
            text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
            background: #54cdf1;
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #54cdf1, #74d7f3);
            background: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #54cdf1, #74d7f3); 
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #54cdf1, #74d7f3);
            background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #54cdf1, #74d7f3);
            border-color: transparent;
        }

        /* The arrow indicating a submenu */
        #cssmenu > ul .has-sub>a::after {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            top: 16px;
            right: 10px;
            width: 0px;
            height: 0px;

            /* Creating the arrow using borders */
            border: 4px solid transparent;
            border-left: 4px solid #3dafea; 
        }

        /* The same arrow, but with a darker color, to create the shadow effect */
        #cssmenu > ul .has-sub>a::before {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            top: 17px;
            right: 10px;
            width: 0px;
            height: 0px;

            /* Creating the arrow using borders */
            border: 4px solid transparent;
            border-left: 4px solid #fff;
        }

        /* Changing the color of the arrow on hover */
        #cssmenu > ul li>a:hover::after, #cssmenu > ul li:hover>a::after {
            border-left: 4px solid #fff;
        }

        #cssmenu > ul li>a:hover::before, #cssmenu > ul li:hover>a::before {
            border-left: 4px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
        }


        /* THE SUBMENUS */
        #cssmenu > ul ul {
            position: absolute;
            left: 150px;
            top: -9999px;
            padding-left: 5px;
            opacity: 0;
            /* The fade effect, created using an opacity transition */
            -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease-in;
            -moz-transition: opacity .3s ease-in;
            -o-transition: opacity .3s ease-in;
            -ms-transition: opacity .3s ease-in;
        }

        /* Showing the submenu when the user is hovering the parent link */
        #cssmenu > ul li:hover>ul {
            top: 0px;
            opacity: 1;
        }
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: The menu is not in the div so of course a mouseout event would fire. The JavaScript has no clue those elements are linked.

Comment: I tried that but it was buggy, sorry I have not made it clear what I have done already...when I nest the menu Div into the Circle Div it seems to onmouseover ok but is buggy when I move the mouse.

Comment: When I try to use your code in jsfiddle, menu is shown far from the circle. Is that correct? Or it should be right near a circle?

Comment: It should be right under it - margin-left:750px; of .cssmenuDiv is supposed to being it close enough for testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres an example...

http://jsfiddle.net/5hnDn/5/

Forget about the js, not required...

```
<div class="divCircle" id="divCircle">
<div id='cssmenu'>    
<ul>
   <li class='active '><a href='index.html'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li class='has-sub '><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li class='has-sub '><a href='#'><span>Product 1</span></a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a></li>
               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li class='has-sub '><a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a></li>
               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a></li>
               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>About</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

...

Only the changes to rules shown below...

```
#divCircle {
    position: relative;
} 

#divCircle:hover #cssmenu {
    display: block;
}
#cssmenu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: -60px;
}

#cssmenu > ul{
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I have done this part ok but am not sure how to keep the menu showing when I move off the circle onto the menu and make the menu disappear when I move off the circle or menu (if that makes sense!)

Comment: thanks - thats perfect, thanks! can you explain where I was going wrong?

Comment: No problem, main thing would be that Im not sure where you were implementing 'circleAnimOff()' so this obviously appears to not get called. The other thing to mention is what you were trying to achieve is typically a 'dropdown' menu and the best way to do this with just CSS is to wrap the menu within a container (in your case, the circle div and apply some positioning rules in relation to each other. This way when your hovering over the circle your also hovering over the menu.

Comment: Thanks - that really helped, I wanted a CSS only solution anyway! 'circleAnimOff()' was not applied as my most recent test was without it and I simply copied and pasted, it was all very buggy: if the 'cssMenu' div was nested inside 'divCircle' div and onmouseover & onmouseout JS was applied to 'divCircle' it would appear ok but then if I moved the mouse (not out of the circle) it would disappear!